# Azure Automation - how to split out common functions

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

I'm wondering if there's a way I can define common functions in a separate runbook in Azure Automation?  For instance, I've got a logging function that timestamps the messages and exits on errors that I use in multiple runbooks.  I'd like to define it once, and then call it from the other runbooks.  And if I change it in the future, I only have to change it in one place.

I know I can define parent / child runbooks and call them inline, which led me to wonder if I could split out, for instance, a function definition and then call that runbook from another runbook to "import" the function into the current runbook.  So for instance, I have a runbook called "Test-FunctionDefinition" with the following code:

```
function Test-FunctionDefintion() {
  param (
    [String] $TestParam
  )
  Write-Output "Output from test function: $TestParam"
}
```

I'd like to be able to call it inline from another runbook like this to define the function, and then be able to use that function:

```
& .\Test-FunctionDefinition.ps1

Test-FunctionDefinition -TestParam "Test String"
```

I tried creating the two runbooks, but while it appears to call the runbook "Test-FunctionDefiniton" fine on line 1, subsequently calling the function on line 3 fails with:

> Test-FunctionDefinition : The term 'Test-FunctionDefinition' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?  I realize I could just modify my runbook and call `& .\Test-FunctionDefinition.ps1 -TestParam "Test String"`, but would prefer to do it the other way if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more testing to make sure my original assumption (defining a function in one script and calling it in another) worked as I expected, and I got the same error. It appears that you need to dot-source rather than use the &. This worked both in a PowerShell console and Azure Automation:

```
. .\Test-FunctionDefinition.ps1

Test-FunctionDefinition -TestParam "Test String"
```

Note the starting '.' instead of '&'. I'll need to look up what the difference is between those...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should be possible - [Create modular runbooks in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-child-runbooks)

You have twop options:

- Inline - Child runbooks run in the same job as the parent.
- Cmdlet - A separate job is created for the child runbook.

For powershell runbook it should be easy as this

```
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "LabRG" -Name "MyVM"
$output = .\PS-ChildRunbook.ps1 -VM $vm -RepeatCount 2 -Restart $true
```

Comment: Yeah, I said I know I can run another runbook Inline using <runbook name>.ps1, and that I'd tried that, but the function defined within wasn't available after calling the other runbook. And your option 2, running it as a cmdlet, means it spawns off another job; the function wouldn't be read into the current job. Ideally, I'd like to define a few functions in a runbook, and then call that runbook from another, and be able to use those functions. It may not be possible; the way you describe may be my best option, and I'd have to split out each function to a separate runbook. But I hope not.